# eCommerce free platform

Tags: gratis, web-apps, web-development, ecommerce

I'm looking for an eCommerce platform to use for a client's website. My requirements are the following:

- Free of charge.
- eCommerce admin dashboard to manage products, clients and orders.
- Much preferably **without a front-end** so that I can build my own (I'll probably build an AngularJS app) and use API requests to connect with the backend. It could also be something that has a front-end but that can be made headless with plug-ins or by removing code.
- "Nice-to-have": a backend that can be hosted in my own server. I.e. unlike Moltin (read below) who host all the eCommerce data in their servers.

Now, I've done my research and found that the closest thing to suit me is [Moltin](https://moltin.com/). My problem with it is that it allows for too few API requests in its free version.

Also, using [Magento](https://magento.com/)'s API has kind of scared me off due to a lack of documentation when it comes to the platforms I'd like to use (AngularJS mainly). I'm still open to using it if you convince me otherwise.

Comment: Maybe [osCommerce](https://www.oscommerce.com/Products)? I've just heard of it and not used it myself - if you try it and like it, answer your own question.

Comment: It's got a bounty. So go ahead and answer it yourself, if you feel like adding some more info :D I'll check it out anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to recommend WooCommerce for WordPress. It should be **exactly** what you are looking for. WooCommerce with Wordpress is,

- Free of charge
- eCommerce admin dashboard to manage products, clients and orders. - Has an awesome backend where you do just that and more
- WooComcerce integrates with WordPress themes, so essentially you would have your app integrated with a WordPress theme and WooCommerce. It should be [simple to integrate](https://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/features/#wc-features-developer-friendly), [read here](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/woocodex/) for more information.
- WordPress & Woocommerce can be installed on your backend with no problems (assuming your server can run PHP and MySQL)

If you have any questions, feel free to comment

## [WooCommerce](https://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/)

> An e-commerce toolkit that helps you sell anything with WordPress.
>
> Transform your WordPress website into a thorough-bred online eCommerce store. Delivering enterprise-level quality & features whilst backed by a name you can trust. Say hello to WooCommerce.
>
> [image: WooCommerce Dashboard UI]

Comment: Do you think I would implement this with my AngularJS app using API requests or embedding PHP code?

Comment: @FaustoNA I do (possible a mixture of both), in fact there are a few guides I would recommend you take a look at like [this one](http://www.roysivan.com/creating-angularjs-app-wordpress-part/#.VqT45PkrIfQ)

Comment: Awesome! I've been researching myself and I've ended up in these articles too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/)? It is a whole ERP, but, because it is modular, you can use just what you want. AFAIK, it has a [REST API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tryton-restful) if you want to access it just like a service.

It has GPL-3 license.

Comment: Looks pretty good, I'll check it out. Unfortunately it's not as specific as Moltin or Magento are. Moltin says they allow 30,000 API requests a month, which should roughly translate to 10k pageviews. Not quite sure if that's enough for my client.